# jquery tabify url id

Tags: jquery

I am using the tabify plugin with jQuery but am having a nightmare trying to get it to work when I use a url before the #id in the href.

The original demo works with url all I have changed is the ids and classes.

Cant work it out at all.

```
    <ul id="tab-box" class="tab-menu">
                <li class="active text-shadow"><a href="dfdf/dfdf.html#overview">Overview</a></li>
                <li ><a href="dfdf/dfdfdf.html#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="overview" class="tab-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec luctus eros. Cras nec diam purus,
vitae condimentum erat. Phasellus erat ligula, rutrum eget suscipit quis, pharetra eu enim. In sit amet velit quam,
feugiat elementum quam. Sed nisi libero, pulvinar non imperdiet vel, consequat ut elit. Curabitur et nisi in
libero elementum pretium.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec luctus eros. Cras nec diam purus,
vitae condimentum erat. Phasellus erat ligula, rutrum eget suscipit quis, pharetra eu enim. In sit amet velit quam,
feugiat elementum quam. Sed nisi libero, pulvinar non imperdiet vel, consequat ut elit. Curabitur et nisi in
libero elementum pretium.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="reviews" class="tab-content">
            <p>

                Let my viciousness be emptied,<br />
                Desire and lust banished,<br />
                Charity and patience,<br />
                Humility and obedience,<br />
                And all the virtues increased.
            </p>
        </div>



.tab-menu { padding:10px 0 5px 0; clear: both; margin-top:10px; overflow:hidden; }

.tab-menu li { display: inline; }

.tab-menu li a {
text-align:center;
padding:10px 15px;
border:2px solid #c4bbc1;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
background: #cdc4c8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cdc4c8 0%, #c6bdc2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cdc4c8), color-stop(100%,#c6bdc2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cdc4c8 0%,#c6bdc2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cdc4c8 0%,#c6bdc2 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cdc4c8 0%,#c6bdc2 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cdc4c8', endColorstr='#c6bdc2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #cdc4c8 0%,#c6bdc2 100%); /* W3C */
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #999999;

}

.tab-menu li a:visited, .tab-menu li a:link {
color:white;
}

.tab-menu li.active a {
border:2px solid #9e8f98;
background: #b2a4a9; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b2a4a9 0%, #9f9098 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b2a4a9), color-stop(100%,#9f9098)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b2a4a9 0%,#9f9098 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b2a4a9 0%,#9f9098 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b2a4a9 0%,#9f9098 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b2a4a9', endColorstr='#9f9098',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #b2a4a9 0%,#9f9098 100%); /* W3C */
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #999999;
}

.tab-content {
float: left;
clear: both;
border: 3px solid #9e8f98;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px;
width: 732px; }

.tab-content p{
margin-bottom:10px;
}




<script>
$('#tab-box').tabify();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes in your URLs are what's breaking it.

There's no real reason to have actual URLs in the tabs as the whole point of tabs is to give the user new content on the current page.

Comment: But if I leave it blank I get redirected to the homepage

Comment: The URLs should coincide with the IDs of your `div`s.  For example `<a href="#overview">Overview</a>` will display the content of `<div id="overview" class="tab-content">`.

Comment: Yeah I understand this, but when I pit #overview I get redirected to http://yoursite/#overview hence why I want to put a url before the #id

Comment: I should point out that the tabs work when I do not use a URL when I do the div that should be hidden is not

Comment: Are you putting `$('#tab-box').tabify();` in the `$(document).ready(function() { });` method?  Do your tabs show up properly or can you see all their content when the page loads?

Comment: Well this works http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/6Y6Pa/1/ and this doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/6Y6Pa/1629/ because of the backslash I put in.  So you obviously have something else outside of the backslashes that is interfering if they are redirecting you with just hash tags in the URL.

Comment: Basically if i use href="#id" with no url before it the tabs work. when I add the url the all the tabs are displayed.

Comment: Well here's your code copied directly into a jsFiddle and it works fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/f7pjF/1/  So you have other code interfering somewhere if it doesn't work for you.  Check for Javascript errors.

Comment: Its really weird the first content div works with a URL when I add the second it throws it out.

Comment: It seems that the base url is messing things up.